# Tomcat manager app and webapps not "seeing" increased JVM memory

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

domain.tld/manager/serverinfo:

```
OK - Server info
Tomcat Version: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
OS Name: Linux
OS Version: 2.6.32-042stab113.11
OS Architecture: amd64
JVM Version: 1.6.0_38-b38
JVM Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
```

On my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine I've increased the JVM memory for Tomcat from `-Xms64m -Xmx128m` to `-Xms256m -Xmx768m` - or so I thought. When I look at the java process after I've restarted Tomcat, everything looks like it has accepted the increased memory.

I start Tomcat with `JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx768m"`, which works according to `top` (process 1842 is the only java process):

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1842 tomcat6   20   0 1455m 162m  11m S    0  2.0   0:16.35 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Xms256m -Xmx768m ...

# cat /proc/1842/cmdline
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Xms256m -Xmx768m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=...
```

But when I look at the manager webapp, I don't see the information I expect. It's the same as before (yes, I've restarted Tomcat and reloaded the page).

domain.tld/manager/status:

```
JVM
Free memory: 15.69 MB Total memory: 78.18 MB Max memory: 113.81 MB
```

I can even force an `Out-of-Java-heap-space` error, which occurs around 126m (as reported by the manager webapp). Clearly, my webapp doesn't see the increased JVM memory. What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**

I ran across the Java Virtual Machine Process Status Tool (`jps`), which gave me a nice little detail: even though you cannot see it with `cat /proc/1842/cmdline`, the old `-Xms64M` and `-Xmx128m` find their way into the JVM (see at the end):

```
# jps -lvm
1842 org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xss192k -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1500 -XX:GCTimeRatio=9 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat6-tomcat6-tmp -Xms64M -Xmx128m
```

Now I only have to find the place where the `-Xms64M` and `-Xmx128m` comes from. Apparently the JVM doesn't care about my parameters, even though they're passed to it (via `setenv.sh`). I started searching but have not found anything yet ...

**EDIT 2**

Somehow `_JAVA_OPTIONS` was set and was overriding the values I specified in `setenv.sh`. I'm now clearing `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and everything is fine.

Comment: At the `virtual memory` as per top command is saying the size is `1455m`. Did you check with jconsole? What does the jconsole say?

Comment: Since the server (headless environment) is running an openjdk JRE I don't have JConsole at my command. Other tools (e.g. `jvmtop`) often require a JDK.